On Histogram, show all months of the year but hide columns that a beyond the selected date

I'm trying to hide these columns.
I have edited the interaction of the chart so that a slicer with the date does not effect it to show all months for the year.
I can do it with calendar_date<=max(calendar_date) however the data I have has data for the entire year, it is also not dynamic with slicer at the top which has the calendar_date in it.
Using selectedvalue doesn't work either.
Perhaps I am just missing something obvious?

Try filtering the fact table so it only returns up to the current month (adjust as necessary):
CurrentMonth = MONTH(TODAY())
CALCULATE([Total Order Quantity],FILTER('DimDate',DimDate[MonthNumberOfYear]<=[CurrentMonth]))

do you have two tables with date? Your calendar date will be in Jun. However, the date in fact table contains the whole year date. Is that your scenario?

Yes, that is correct.
